# Полностью отключить кэширование nginx

Tags: nginx, кэширование

Файл `nginx.conf`

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1s; //добавил от отчаяния)

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_cache off;
        }
        location /basic_status {
            stub_status;
        }
        location /style {
            root C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/;
            proxy_cache off;
        }
        location /img {
            root C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/;
            proxy_cache off;
        }
        location /js {
            root C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/;
            proxy_cache off;

        }
        location /favicon.ico {
            root C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/;
        }

       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь решить проблему уже несколько часов. В документации так много модулей, связанных с кэшем, что я в них просто запутался.

**UPD:** Скриншот заголовков

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скрипт автоматически удалил приветствие. Теперь вопрос стал похож на требование

Comment: поставь в `server` вот что: `expires -1;` http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires

Comment: @norbornen, не помогает. Я и ноут перегружал уже.

Comment: ну ладно. "кеширование" какого из этих `location` ты отключаешь? как проверяешь отключено ли кеширование? скриншоты заголовков ответа добавь в вопрос

Comment: @norbornen, отключить кеширование надо полностью (во сех `location`). До этого проверял - отсутствием вносимых изменений в скриптах, стилях). Скрин добавил...после каждого изменения конфига, в командной строке  вводил команду `nginx -s reload`

Comment: добавь `if_modified_since off;` и убедись, что `nginx -t` не сообщает о проблемах

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76545/discussion-between--and-norbornen).

Comment: @norbornen, ничего не помогает. `nginx: the configuration file c:\nginx-1.12.2/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok`  Можете привести пример правильного конфига для отключения кеша?

Answer (score 1):

Отключение кэширования на сервере:

```
proxy_cache off; # Значение по умолчанию.
```

Отключение кэширования на клиентe:

```
expires epoch; # Или любое другое прошедшее время.
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как в вопросе речь идёт о статике, можно сделать вот так:

```
location /js/ {
    root C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/; # возможно тут не нужен концевой слеш - не знаю как в windows правильно

    add_header          Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header          Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since   off;
    expires             off;
    etag                off;
}
```